# adding another condition to a inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables - customers and the order list

I want to bring for the tables the following:
 the list of all the items they bought but only for the customers that their customer id ends with **9**

This is my code:

```
Select customers.customerid, itemsordered.customerid,itemsordered.item   
from itemsordered, customers
where customers.customerid = itemsordered.customerid
```

Now - I don't understand how to add the second condition
I think i should write something like -  `LIKE customers.customerid “%9”;`

I am not sure, and if its correct, i don't understand where in the query to write it

Thank you

ivgi

Comment: I think this `customers.id % 10 = 9` should work as well. I wouldn't use wildcards for integers in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select c.customerid, i.customerid, i.item   
from itemsordered i
inner join customers c on c.customerid = i.customerid
                      and c.id % 10 = 9
```

Comment: How about `customers.id % 10 = 9`?

Comment: Yes, should work too. There are many possibilities to do that.

Comment: I actually liked your idea better and used it in my answer.

Comment: NP :) anyway I think wildcards is bad idea here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `AND` operator and your new condition:

```
SELECT customers.customerid, itemsordered.customerid,itemsordered.item   
FROM   itemsordered, customers
WHERE  customers.customerid = itemsordered.customerid
AND    customers.customerId LIKE '%9';
```

Comment: That's not stated in the OP `-)

Comment: I think that's a straightforward assumption (it's ends with id..)

Comment: @user3052235 Glad to help! Please click "accept" on the answer to signal that it really helped you.